# Can a wave exist on the “face” of a wave?

Tags: visible-light, waves, photons, electrons

It would seem that this would be possible with waves in water. What about other waves Clarification:
Given a wave starting from a point of impact, in water, at: Time 0:00 and xyz 0,0,0 and the impacting “object” came from 0,0,h.   At some time it would reach its first maximum wave height, say z=10.  If at that instant an impact coming from 0,0,5 traveling along the x axis impacted the “face” of the first wave, the second wave would initially propagate as though it had impacted a flat surface, but it is not a flat surface, nor is it a stationary nor a stable surface.  It seems if would be a curved (initially around 0,0,0 and than over each peak and trough) “undulating” surface and additionally an EXPANDING surface.  I suppose this is complicated enough although manageable to think about. And that brings me to the question:  What about other waves (light . . ?) 
Added 2-22-2014: I really don’t think anyone has understood what I am getting at; undoubtedly my fault. 
The classic “Bulls Eye” water wave table pattern is relatively stable, long lived. 
Imagine an impact to the face (NOT another impact from above) of the first wave as it reached its first peak. . .
Well it turns out what I was trying to describe with a wave table and then question if it would be applicable to light is well depicted; by/as:  Photon Electron Junctions in Feynman diagrams and the intricacies of particle interaction.

Comment: YES, it hapens with light. See: Photon Electron Junctions in Feynman diagrams and the intricacies of particle interaction.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure I've understood your question but I think you're asking if a big wave can have wave-features on its large features.  If so, sure, why not?  You can add waves of different frequencies to achieve results like:

[image: waves added together]

Comment: Please see my:”Clarification:”  in the original question. Thanks’

Comment: Your question is about something splashing in water which is somewhat of a special case for waves because you can't really choose the frequency of the splashes, just the amplitude.  With my image the frequency of the small wave is much higher than the large wave.  I think the answer to a more generic version of your question is pictured in my answer.

Comment: Assuming your drawing is a z,x section; (forgetting about your secondary wave) I am asking about a wave caused by an impact coming from the left, impacting the FACE. Ignoring the slope; wouldn’t the 2nd wave initially propagate in y,z  as the face move along x.

Comment: Not for long.  They need gravity to continue to propagate so they would't end up like how you're imagining.

Comment: Ah, Gravity; there’s the wrinkle with this analogy, thanks’.